# Using lm and predict on data in matrices

Tags: r, dataframe, lm, predict

I use `R` only a little bit and never use data frames, which makes understanding the correct use of predict difficult.  I have my data in plain matrices, not data frames, call them `a` and `b`, which are `N x p` and `M x p` matrices respectively.  I can run the regression `lm(a[,1] ~ a[,-1])`.  I would like to use the resulting `lm` object to predict `b[,1]` from `b[,-1]`.  My naive guess of `predict(lm(a[,1] ~ a[,-1]), b[,-1])` doesn't work.  What's the right syntax to use the `lm` to get a vector of predictions?

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean in your question? And why not just use `data.frame`'s.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra because I don't understand how to use `data.frame`s.  That's the question. I tried a few plausible options to turn my stuff into data frames, and that didn't seem to work.  I'm sure the answer is really simple, I'm just frustrated guessing at the syntax.

Comment: Please make your example reproducible.

Comment: You tried `a <- as.data.frame( a )?`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store a whole matrix in one column of a `data.frame`:

```
x <- a [, -1]
y <- a [,  1]
data <- data.frame (y = y, x = I (x))
str (data)
## 'data.frame':    10 obs. of  2 variables:
## $ y: num  0.818 0.767 -0.666 0.788 -0.489 ...
## $ x: AsIs [1:10, 1:9] 0.916274.... 0.386565.... 0.703230.... -2.64091.... 0.274617.... ...

model <- lm (y ~ x)
newdata <- data.frame (x = I (b [, -1]))
predict (model, newdata) 
##         1         2 
## -3.795722 -4.778784
```

The paper about the pls package, ([Mevik, B.-H. and Wehrens, R. The pls Package: Principal Component and Partial Least Squares Regression in R Journal of Statistical Software, 2007, 18, 1 - 24.](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v18/i02/)) explains this technique.

Another example with a spectroscopic data set (quinine fluorescence), is in [`vignette ("flu")`](http://hyperspec.r-forge.r-project.org/blob/flu.pdf) of my package hyperSpec.

Answer (score 2):

To make `data.fram`'s out of your matrices, simply do:

```
m = matrix(runif(100), 10, 10)
df = as.data.frame(m)
```

And perform linear regression:

```
lm_result = lm(V1 ~ V100, df)
predicted_values = predict(lm_result, b)
```

Or for multiple regression:

```
lm_result = lm(V1 ~ V2 + V3 + V4, df)
predicted_values = predict(lm_result, b)
```

assuming the columns `V1` - `V4` are present in `b`.

Comment: But how would you generalize this to many predictors (the OP's case)?

Comment: Thanks. Still a bit tricky when `p` (the number of predictors) is not known a priori.

Comment: Or quite large. I have many predictors.  Do I have to specify each one?

Comment: You can create the formula on the fly, e.g. `as.formula(sprintf("V1 ~ %s", paste(names(df)[2:4], collapse = " + ")))`.

Comment: But performing linear regression with hundreds of predictors is dodgy, you are probably fitting a lot of noise.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra It's not hundreds, maybe 10. But `V2+v3+..` seems a bit clunky.

Comment: You can put the matrix into *one* column of a data.frame (see my answer). This saves the hassle of pasting a formula, keeps together what belongs together, and you can even have other columns in the data.frame that are not used by the model.

Answer (score 1):

You could compute the predictions manually:

```
> fit <- lm(a[,1] ~ a[,-1])
> fit$coefficients[1] + b[,-1] %*% fit$coefficients[-1]
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    5
```

Here, `fit$coefficients[1]` is the intercept, and `fit$coefficients[-1]` are the remaning coefficients (and `%*%` is matrix multiplication).

Comment: This is the approach I've used before, but I wanted to try to use some of the features of the predict function.  It's nice and easy.

Comment: This is fast, but comes at the cost of not having the bells and whistles of `predict` (confidence intervals, prediction intervals).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using lm inside a function to cycle through many different linear models then perform leave-one-out cross validation for predictions.  @PaulHiemstra 's sprintf did the trick.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).